# Как искать слова в терминале Bash , аналог поиска cntr+f в браузере?

Tags: linux, bash

Использую терминал Bash на виндовсе , после некоторых команд
(например в Laravel это `php artisan`  ) выводится  много текста , мне нужно использовать поиск в этом тексте , аналог **cntr+f**  в браузере ,

Как сделать поиск в тексте терминала bash ?

Comment: выводить в файл вместо (или одновременно (tee)) вывода на экран и потом делать grep по этому файлу. или вывод самой команды сразу отдавать grep (если команда быстро выполняемая)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поиска в mingw  нужно использовать alt+F3  или правая кнопка *search*.

Answer (score 1):

К башу или zsh это не имеет отношение. Все зависит только от используемого терминала. К примеру, в xfce4-terminal, в gnome terminal (в свежих убунтах/минтах) это ctrl+shift+f. В других терминалах надо искать. В xterm [чуточку сложнее](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109509/how-to-search-xterm-console-history) но также возможно.

Но есть общий способ - вывод команды перенаправить в less. В большинстве случаев это просто дописать в конец `| less`. В некоторых случаях можно дописать ещё параметр -r - `| less -r`, что бы цвета выводились. А дальше все будет просто и красиво. Если надо искать - жмем слеш <kbd>/</kbd> и вводим текст + . Искать дальше - <kbd>n</kbd>, назад - <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. Перейти в самый конец - <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>. Выход - <kbd>q</kbd>. Кто с вимом дружит, тот найдет команды простыми и очевидными.

Но есть проблема - если программа решила выводить в stderr. В этом случае можно перенаправить его в stdout

```
./somecommad 2>&1 | less
```

Comment: Все настроил команда 
`php artisan | less`   нажимаю Enter  потом \    текст  для поиска, но проблема в том что ,  php artisan | less никакого текста не выводит для поиска, только выводит   **stdout is not a tty**

Comment: так текст вообще никакой не выводит? (да и слеш надо ставить `/`)

Comment: После  ввода [этой команды](https://ibb.co/cgPQwK) получаю вот эти результаты [снимок 1](https://ibb.co/kQLb3z) ,   [снимок 2](https://ibb.co/gD1iiz)

Comment: стоп-стоп-стоп. А где же линукс? у Вас mingw терминал. Но очень похоже, что у Вас все выводится в stderr.

Comment: @a_mine убедитесь, что пейджер less или more есть в наличае. почитайте про поддержку конвейера в "виндовс"

Comment: но в mingw терминале ctrl-F вроде как работает

Comment: Да у меня  mingw терминал на виндовсе  но   ctrl-F не работает

Answer (score 0):

На линуксе это делается так:
`CTRL+SHIFT+F`